# friendly_id 4.0.8 with rails 3.0.1 rails generate friendly_id not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, friendly-id

I am using friendly_id 4.0.8 with rails 3.0.1. I want to use the history feature.

When I type the command `rails generate friendly_id`, it fails with the following error message:

```
[WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/friendly_id_generator". Error: ActiveRecord is not missing constant Migration!.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:479:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `rake_original_const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `rake_original_const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/friendly_id-4.0.8/lib/generators/friendly_id_generator.rb:8
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.
```

Is there some different syntax to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I have got it working currently by manually generating a migration script with

```
rails generate migration create_friendly_id_slugs
```

Then replace the contents of the migration script with that from gems/friendly_id-4.0.8/lib/friendly_id/migration.rb as follows:

```
class CreateFriendlyIdSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :friendly_id_slugs do |t|
      t.string   :slug,           :null => false
      t.integer  :sluggable_id,   :null => false
      t.string   :sluggable_type, :limit => 40
      t.datetime :created_at
    end
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_id
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type], :unique => true
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_type
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :friendly_id_slugs
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`